# Where can I find a new water key (spit valve) for an Olds Ambassador trombone?

Tags: repair, trombone

I got a pretty nice Olds Ambassador from Goodwill. There was duct tape over the spit valve -- the whole water key assembly is missing.

I think I could repair it myself, but am not quite sure where to find the part. I don't see many online.

Does anyone know if other trombones or brass instruments use similar enough water keys that I could substitute? And where I could find one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any local repair shop can order this part from a brass supply company like Allied Supply for about $15 + shipping. It needs to be soldered onto the slide. This is special solder ordered from a brass supply company for which they use an acetylene tank. This is an uncommon setup for the everyday person.

However, most shops (like mine) charge ~$25 total for this service. Its a common repair.

Comment: This will probably work. However, considering F E Olds has been out of business thirty-something years, the cost of the key may be more expensive than some other company which is still producing parts.

Comment: Indeed; there's really no reason to try to find an original F.E. Olds key assembly when a present-day part will work just fine.

Comment: I looked in the Allied Supply catalog, you can definitely get parts for the Olds Ambassador. However, I agree in that it would be cost effective and prudent for a repair shop to see if a universal water key would work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is special solder needed?